# TimePicker displays value 0 always in the default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm developing a component in React JS with `import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';`

The default values it's always 0.

I have define a function like :

```
function getCurrentHours (){
  return moment().format('HH');
}

<TimePicker 
    style={{ width: 50 }}
    defaultValue={getCurrentHours()}
    hideDisabledOptions
    disabledHours={getDisabledHours} /*horas que não podem ser selecionadas*/
    showSecond={false} 
    showMinute={false}
    {...rest}
    selected={this.state.selectedDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/react-component/time-picker#timepicker-1) the defaultValue needs to be a moment objec. `moment.format` returns a string, try passing the default value as a moment object.

```
function getCurrentHours (){
  return moment();
}
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vq7yzo5z6)

Comment: what does your rest object look like? where is your `getCurrentHours` located?